# Change Columns to be queried in the table dynamically in Spark Project

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, config

I am running a below SQL query in Spark 2.3 as shown below :

```
val dataJoin = s"""SELECT
                date,
                a.mth,
        weekday,
        if(a.x_days=b.x_days,b.y,c.z) as total,
        case when (a.x - day(date)) +1 <=0 then 1
                         when (a.x - day(date)) +1 > 366 then 999
                         else (a.x - day(date)) +1  end  as glt,
        GROSS
        FROM tableA a 
        left join tableB b
        on a.mth = b.mth and a.x_days=b.x_days"""

val data =sparkVal.sql(dataJoin)
```

I want to make the query Dynamic , i.e If I want to select more columns or less columns ,the module should not be touched, just changing in a single place should help.

How to make it achieve it? Is there way to configure like this, XML or something?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to modify the columns in the select clause of the query.

You can do string interpolation with ${} in the `s"""` syntax. The dynamic columns could be stored in a list separately and then concatenated using mkString(",").
You could do something like below

```
val sel_list = List("date","a.mth","weekday").mkString(",")

val dataJoin = s"""SELECT
           ${sel_list} ,
    if(a.x_days=b.x_days,b.y,c.z) as total,
    case when (a.x - day(date)) +1 <=0 then 1
                     when (a.x - day(date)) +1 > 366 then 999
                     else (a.x - day(date)) +1  end  as glt,
    GROSS
    FROM tableA a
    left join tableB b
    on a.mth = b.mth and a.x_days=b.x_days"""
   println(dataJoin)
```

results

```
SELECT
           date,a.mth,weekday , 
    if(a.x_days=b.x_days,b.y,c.z) as total,
    case when (a.x - day(date)) +1 <=0 then 1
                     when (a.x - day(date)) +1 > 366 then 999
                     else (a.x - day(date)) +1  end  as glt,
    GROSS
    FROM tableA a
    left join tableB b
    on a.mth = b.mth and a.x_days=b.x_days
```